# get jsx compiler to ignore lines referring to other APIs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, reactjs

I'm using React.js to make components in a chrome content script.

The react components should re-render when the data in local storage changes.

```
readUserInfo : function() {
  chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(object changes, string areaName) {
    this.setState({userInfo:changes["userInfo"].newValue});
});
```

with a mount function

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.readUserInfo();
}
```

of course the jsx compiler complains about the chrome API calls. How can I get the jsx compiler to ignore this line, i.e. leave it as vanilla js?

Comment: The jsx compiler would complain about that because `function(object changes, string areaName) {` is invalid JavaScript.  There are no types in js.  Also don't forget to `.bind(this)` your callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(this.onChromeStorageChange)
},
onChromeStorageChange: function(changes, areaName) {
   this.setState({ userInfo:changes["userInfo"].newValue })
}
```

I used React’s autobinding and removed the invalid argument expression you had (probably copy/pasted from the docs). Don’t forget to remove the listener when the component unmounts.